# calling a function returning boolean in another function

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean

I have the following function that I need to call in another function. I dont know how to do it?

```
private int IsValidUser()
{            
    int result = 0;
    string strQuery = "Select Email From AUser Where Email = @Email And Password = @Password ";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
    //Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
    con.Open();

    result = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        //Session["SessionEmail"] = txtEmail.Text;
        Session[General.S_USEREMAIL] = txtEmail.Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/frmMyAccountMyProfile.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Literal1.Text = "Invalid Email/Password!";
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it as below on button click event.

```
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Authenticate User
    bool blnValidUser = false;
    IsValidUser();
    blnValidUser = Convert.ToBoolean(IsValidUser().result.Value);
    if (blnValidUser)
    {
        // on Success - If remember me > Save to cookies
        //SaveUserDetailsToCookie();                       
    }
    else
    {
        // on Failure - Show error msg
    }
}
```

Comment: IsValidUser() doesn't return value

Comment: `IsValidUser` returns an `int` which clearly has no `result` property.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `IsValidUser` is designed to return an int

(for whatever reason is unknown to me, because it returns nothing. this code will never compile.)

you can fix it, by having it return a `bool` like this:

```
private bool IsValidUser()
{
        int result = 0;
        //since executeScalar is intended to retreive only a single value
        //from a query, we select the number of results instead of the email address
        //of each matching result.
        string strQuery = "Select COUNT(Email) From AUser Where Email = @Email And Password = @Password ";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        //Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
        con.Open();

        result = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        //returning a boolean comparator works like this :
        //will return true if the result is greater than zero, but false if it is not.
        return result > 0;
}
```

and then you can call your function like this:

```
blnValidUser = IsValidUser();
```

Comment: (what i'm leaving out of the example, is that it's better *not* to do DAL related calls in methods like this, and that you still need to close your connection) but that was not part of the question.

Comment: Not only can it work, it's *designed* to, but rather designed to retreive a single value (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html )
I didn't check your mysql statement, but now you mention it, it makes no sense. i'll update the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

`IsValidUser` returns an `int` which clearly has no `result` property. But i assume that you just want to use that value:

```
int valUserResult = IsValidUser();
bool blnValidUser = valUserResult == 1;
```

But you should consider to return a `bool` in the first place because that would be more readable:

```
private bool IsValidUser()
{            
    bool result = false;
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modify the function as below**

```
private int IsValidUser()
   {
    int result = 0;
    string strQuery = "Select Email From AUser Where Email = @Email And Password = @Password ";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
    //Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
    con.Open();

    result = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        //Session["SessionEmail"] = txtEmail.Text;
        Session[General.S_USEREMAIL] = txtEmail.Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/frmMyAccountMyProfile.aspx");
    }

    else
    {
        Literal1.Text = "Invalid Email/Password!";
    }
     return result;

}
}
```

**And call it as follows**

```
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Authenticate User
    int blnValidUser = IsValidUser();
    //Check if blnValidUser is greater than 0.
    //IsValidUser() will return value greater than 0 if the sql is successful else will return 0
    if (blnValidUser > 0)
    {
        // on Success - If remember me > Save to cookies
        //SaveUserDetailsToCookie();                       
    }
    else
    {
        // on Failure - Show error msg

    }
}
```